# Requesting a "quick search" be added to watched tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, search, tag-search

So, we have this lovely watched tags box on the main Stack Overflow home page

[image]

Where you can click on the individual tags to do a quick search on a per-tag basis. I'd like to see an extra link added:

[image]

Clicking this new link would just do a tag search, where it concatonates all watched tags with "or". So, in my example, it would take you here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css+or+html+or+javascript+or+jquery+or+php+or+postgresql+or+sql

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags?

Comment: @SamuelLiew The options there are very confusing for me because they have different functionalities (my tags & no answer = filter VS newest & votes = sorting)

Comment: @SamuelLiew Using just the UI, how do I even get to that URL from the homepage?

Comment: Click on "Answer questions" first to see this special link. Oh, and you must be on "Stack Overflow", not "Home".

Comment: Yeah, good point Andre. "My Tags" and "No Answers" are two non-mutually-exclusive filters. "All Questions" is a non-filter. And "Newest" and "Votes" are just sorting options that could be combined with any of the filters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like your request has been fulfilled. You can now use the "*filter*" button and then select the "*My watched tags*" radio button. After clicking "*Apply filter*" or hitting <kbd>ENTER</kbd> you will get the results for the tags found under your "*Watched Tags*"

[image]

**Note**: In order to see the filter button you need to be on the [questions page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions)

Answer (score 12):

As there is no similar feature, I've decided to build it directly into my [Advanced Search Helper, Saved Search (Bookmarks), and Navigation Improvements](https://stackapps.com/q/7971/9011) userscript.

[image]

**Features:**

1. Search main/meta switcher
2. Switch to main/meta from left sidebar
3. Order-by selector
4. Username & Tag autocomplete
5. Saved searches!
6. and now... **include watched & exclude ignored tags**!!!